# Need a regex for a json String

Tags: java, regex, json

I have a string of the form

```
String test="{\"{\"name\":\"alex\", \"age\":20}\",\"{\"name\":\"peter\", \"age\":24}\"}";
```

I need to find a regex in java so that I can parse out in the form:

```
{\"name\":\"alex\",\"age\":20}
{\"name\":\"peter\",\"age\":24}
```

Comment: Use a json Parser instead of regex.

Comment: @Jens Actually this is not valid JSON so regex may be correct tool here, unless OP real data looks like `[{"name":"alex", "age":20},{"name":"peter", "age":24}]`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to parse json then **you should use a json parser**. There are many json parser like Jackson, Gson, Json.simple.

But if you want to use a regex you can use a regex like this:

```
"name":"(.*?)",\s*"age":(\d+)
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/qV7kP9/1)**

```
MATCH 1
1.  [11-15] `alex`
2.  [24-26] `20`
MATCH 2
1.  [39-44] `peter`
2.  [53-55] `24`
```

Comment: While it might be correct answer, it's very very bad practice.. You should advice  OP to use a parser

Comment: @MarounMaroun thanks for the comment I've already put `you should use a json parser` although but I posted the regex in case OP wants it :)